# Calculate column data

Tags: java, csv

i'm trying to create a void method that will read csv file and count the reputaion number of state such that how many times TX,how many times Oh and how many times of Dc. the out should be-TX=4; Oh=2;DC=2. but my out put is "For input string: "F" "- and i really couldn't get where is the problem.can someone help me?

"Crimerate.csv"

State county Rate

Tx,DALLAs,39

TX,Aderson,10

Oh,Archer,20

DC,DC,50

Tx,Houston,31

TX,Claude,13

Oh,Bexar,10
DC,SE,40

```
public static void countnumber()

{

        try{

    List<String>number=Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Crimerate.csv"));


            double sum=0,num=0;

            for (String line:number){

                if(num==0){

                    ++num;

                    continue;

                }

                line=line.replace("\"","");

                String []result=line.split(",");



                double close = Double.parseDouble(result[6]);

                String numberAsString = Double.toString(close);



                if(numberAsString.equals("Tx"))
                {
                    sum++;
                    System.out.println("number of Tx =" + sum);
                }
                else if(numberAsString.equals("Oh"))
                {
                    sum++;
                    System.out.println("number of Oh =" + sum);
                }
                else if(numberAsString.equals("Dc"))
                {
                    sum++;
                    System.out.println("number of Dc =" + sum);
                }
                }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }


public static void main (String args[])

{

countnumber();

}
```

Comment: you are incrementing the same sum variable on each if statements

Comment: Wasn't this question asked just a few days ago? In any event, there needs to be a counter for each "State". Also, for some reason, the states have both "Tx" and "TX", so it should be `numberAsString.equalsIgnoreCase()`. A better solution would be to convert the state to a uniform case, and use a `Map<String,Integer>` to track rather than attempting to list out all of the states.

Answer (score 1):

While the previously suggested answers will address the specific question of why there was only a single response (a result of having only a single sum variable), they have two issues.

- They are not accounting for the fact that in the example data, Texas is shown both as "Tx" and "TX". Thus, the current other answers will not give the correct result of 4 for Texas (they will only show 2).
- The approaches assume that the full data set was shown. If other states are present, then the code would need to be continually expanded to support the new states.

This solution handles both situations.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Map<String, Integer> countByState = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> number;
    try {
        number = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("f:/tmp/Crimerate.csv"));

        int cntr = 0;
        for (String line : number) {
            // skip first line
            if (cntr++ == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            String []result=line.split(",");   

            // should add error checking
            String state = result[0].toUpperCase();

            Integer cnt = countByState.get(state);
            if (cnt == null) {
                cnt = new Integer(0);
            }
            countByState.put(state, ++cnt);

        }            

        System.out.println(countByState);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sample Results based upon the data presented in the question (there is only one DC in that data):

> {TX=4, OH=2, DC=1}

Comment: @user6167014, glad to help. If appropriate, would you consider accepting this answer?

Comment: @user6167014, [this page on answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) provides a bit more detail on my request. Thanks, and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

```
               int txCount = 0;   
               int ohCount = 0;
               int dcCount = 0;  //create this variables inside the class(instance variables)


                if(numberAsString.equals("Tx"))
                {
                    ++txCount;
                    System.out.println("number of Tx =" + txCount);
                }
                else if(numberAsString.equals("Oh"))
                {
                    ++ohCount;
                    System.out.println("number of Oh =" + ohCount);
                }
                else if(numberAsString.equals("Dc"))
                {
                    ++dcCount;
                    System.out.println("number of Dc =" + dcCount);
                } //its better if u use equalsIgnoreCase on if Statements
```

you were referring to same sum variable on each if loops, i have fixed that .
i assume that the code you have written on reading the file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You just need different `sum` variables for each sum. And print the results after the loop.

```
try{

    List<String>number=Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Crimerate.csv"));


        double sumTx=0,sumOh=0,sumDc=0,num=0;

        for (String line:number){

            if(num==0){
                ++num;
                continue;
            }

            line=line.replace("\"","");

            String []result=line.split(",");

            double close = Double.parseDouble(result[6]);
            String numberAsString = Double.toString(close);

            if(numberAsString.equals("Tx")) {
                sumTx++;   
            } else if(numberAsString.equals("Oh")){
                sumOh++;
            } else if(numberAsString.equals("Dc")){
                sumDc++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("number of Tx =" + sumTx);
        System.out.println("number of Oh =" + sumOh);
        System.out.println("number of Dc =" + sumDc);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
}
```